# Identify browsing location in Chrome history

Tags: google-chrome, history

I understand that Chrome syncs the browsing history between my home and office PCs.  Is there a way to distinguish browsing location in the history?  Can my office network detect what I am browsing at home and flag it if I did not actually browse the site in the office?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the restricted the things  to being synced  so please check the option Choose what to sync while sign in from other computer and limit the things which you need to sync from other computer instead of finding the browsing location to restrict.